# How to redirect cname (route 53) to the right application with nginx or jetty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jetty

I have a question about redirecting a cname record through nginx and jetty, this is the situation:

I'm having 3 jetty applications running spingboot war files, there are running on /admin, /application1 and /application2. the admin application makes cname records in route 53 and the admin app has a database with a table to know if it's application 1 or 2.

The 3 applications are on 1 AWS server running nginx and jetty and i want to make the cname record go to the right application without the slash after the name.

Example: i'm making a cname record in the admin application website1.example.com and website2.example.com this will create 2 cnames in route 53 and website 1 has application1 in the admin database and website 2 is application2 in the admin database. because in route53 you cannot define /application1 or /application2 i want to ask how nginx or jetty does this to differentiate the application?

Basic nginx configuration:

```
upstream jetty-backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 40;
}
 server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  location / {

proxy_pass              http://jetty-backend;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_set_header        Connection "";
proxy_intercept_errors  on;
error_page              404 =404 /errors/40x.html;
error_page              405 =405 /errors/40x.html;
error_page              501 =501 /errors/50x.html;
error_page              502 =502 /errors/50x.html;
error_page              503 =503 /errors/50x.html;
  }
  }
}
```

Basic jetty configuration:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" 
 "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/application1</Set>
  <Set name="war">/home/ubuntu/retail/application1.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

So if i type aplication1.example.com i want to go to application 1 and not go to application1.example.com/application1

Do i do this with configuring virtual servers in nginx?

Thank you for the help in advance.
I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: "Do i do this with configuring virtual servers in nginx?" Yes, that's exactly how you do this.

Comment: can i ask you some reference please how to?

Comment: There are countless tutorials out there for setting up virtual hosts in Nginx if you take a few seconds to do a search.

Comment: Thank you for your time. but how does the virtual host redirect knows what app he must choose? because the subdomain does not go through the admin app. it only gets like website1 or another name like website123.example.com how does it know that it need to take application1

Comment: I don't understand the question. You would have Nginx intercepting all traffic on ports 80/443. You would then configure it to know each domain/subdomain you are hosting on your server via virtual hosts, and where the content for each domain/subdomain exists on the server. There would be no redirect happening.

Comment: so i have 2 app and an admin app on the same server, so if i make a subdomain for site1.example.com it must go to app1 but if i make like site2.example.com it has to go to app 2, so i can't just add those 2 as a virtual server right because if i make site3(app1) site4(app2) site5(app1) site6(app2) it has to know what app it needs to go right? i can't just endlessly make virtual servers right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can't, i made another app to redirect to the right apps thx for the help all.